# Python retrieving data from its memory address

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I currently have a very large dataset (~15 GB) which should be used by multiple python scripts at the same time.

Loading single elements of the dataset takes too long, so the whole dataset has to be in memory.

My current best approach would be to have a python process which has all the elements loaded, and have the other python scripts request the element via a socket connection to localhost.

However, then again I have the problem of having to encode and decode the data send via the socket. So my next best Idea was the following, however, I do not know if this is possible:

1. Have the scripts send a request containing the indeces of the datapoints in the dataset they would like to use via a socket to the process having the data
2. Have the process having the data return the memory address of the datapoints
3. Have the script load the elements from there

So the question is if this is possible?

Best regards

Comment: What is your question then? How to get the memory address of your data? Note that even though that is probably possible, it has high chances of being buggy, insecure, etc. rather than dealing with all of these you might as well send the data along whatever way you are communicating. You also probably should look into optimizing data access rather than creating workarounds like this.

Comment: processes generally only have access to a *virtual address* which isn't shared across processes. You would have to use explicitly shared memory, but you need to provide more details about exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Well, I think I cant be more optimal than loading a tensorflow dataset. The specific use case is have different training scripts access the same dataset. However, training should be able to be started independent of each other. So I cant put everything into a single script.

Answer (score 0):

We are a little sparse on details here, but here is a solution matching your request. I assumed your data was approximately tabular (like CSV or pandas.DataFrame) and had consistent data types in each field.

To use this,

- update the `DATA_FIELDS`, `STRUCT_FMT_STR`, `ENCODING`, and `STR_WIDTH` information to match your data
- update provider to load your data instead of the toy data I created
- run provider and wait until it marks 'ready'
- start as many consumers as you want by reexecuting the script with the consumer argument.

If you are doing alot of testing, (such as edit the script, run it, check the results, edit rerun check, and so on), you can start a provider, and then repeatedly run your tests with consumers without having to reload the data since consumers can start and die repeatedly as long as the provider is still alive.

If you have alot of strings and/or your strings can be really long, this can waste alot of space, and you may want to consider storing the strings separately to save space.

Let me know if you have any questions, I tried to put in lots of comments to help explain the logic, hopefully it helps.

```
# Default libraries
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as sm
import sys
import uuid
import struct

# PyPi libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # Used only for convenience

# How wide can your strings get?
STR_WIDTH = 1024
# Data set size used only for generating fake data
DATA_SET_SIZE = int(1e6)

# A unique name that other processes can find the memory by
SHARED_MEMORY_NAME = 'SPECIAL_NAME_FOR_QUASI_77500330'
# Some example data, update yours to match the data you want to process
DATA_FIELDS = [
    ('id', str),
    ('num1', int),
    ('num2', float),
    ('num3', float),
    ('num4', float)
]
# A format string which matches the data above
STRUCT_FMT_STR = f'<{STR_WIDTH}sqddd'
# Calculate the stride
STRUCT_SIZE = struct.calcsize(STRUCT_FMT_STR)
# Will store the total number of samples for convenience
MEM_SIZE_FMT_STR = '<q'
MEM_SIZE_SIZE = struct.calcsize(MEM_SIZE_FMT_STR)
# What encoding to store strings in
#   (if you change this, update struct format string too)
ENCODING = 'UTF-8'
# The path to your dataset or whatever, I used CSV for convenience
FPATH = '77500330_tmp.csv'

# This function puts data into the shared memory buffer
def put(sm, pos, *argc):
    # Strings have to be stored as bytes strings, so convert those
    outargs = [
        bytes(x, encoding=ENCODING) if type(x) is str else x for x in argc
    ]
    
    # Slot the data into the buffer
    posa = MEM_SIZE_SIZE + pos * STRUCT_SIZE
    posb = MEM_SIZE_SIZE + (pos + 1) * STRUCT_SIZE
    sm.buf[posa: posb] = struct.pack(STRUCT_FMT_STR, *outargs)

# This function gets data from the shared memory buffer
def get(sm, pos):
    # Retrieve the data from the buffer
    posa = MEM_SIZE_SIZE + pos * STRUCT_SIZE
    posb = MEM_SIZE_SIZE + (pos + 1) * STRUCT_SIZE
    res = struct.unpack(STRUCT_FMT_STR, sm.buf[posa: posb])
    # Strings from bytes (see put)
    outval = [
        str(x.rstrip(b'\x00'), encoding=ENCODING) if type(x) is bytes else x
        for x in res
    ]
    return outval

# This function stores the number of samples in the buffer
#   makes it easier for consumers to know how much there is
def putsize(sm, total_samples):
    size = struct.pack(MEM_SIZE_FMT_STR, total_samples)
    sm.buf[0: MEM_SIZE_SIZE] = size

# This function retrieves the number of samples in the buffer
def getsize(sm):
    size = struct.unpack(MEM_SIZE_FMT_STR, sm.buf[0:struct.calcsize('<q')])
    return size[0]

# This is a function that makes data for my testing
#   you don't need it after you learn to get the provider/consumer working
def makedata():
    print('makedata')
    
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
    
    id = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for i in range(DATA_SET_SIZE)]
    num1 = rng.integers(0, 1e3, size=DATA_SET_SIZE)
    num2 = rng.random(size=DATA_SET_SIZE)
    num3 = rng.random(size=DATA_SET_SIZE)
    num4 = rng.random(size=DATA_SET_SIZE)
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'id': id, 'num1': num1, 'num2': num2, 'num3': num3, 'num4': num4},
        columns=[x[0] for x in DATA_FIELDS])
    data = data.astype({x[0]: x[1] for x in DATA_FIELDS})
    
    data.to_csv(FPATH)

# This function acts as the provider for the data
#   It must live as long as any consumer still needs data
#   Consumers can be started at any point after this reports 'ready'
def provider():
    print('provider started')
    # Replace this line with however you read your data
    data = pd.read_csv(FPATH, index_col=0)
    # This calculates the total size of the memory buffer to allocate
    total_size = MEM_SIZE_SIZE + len(data) * STRUCT_SIZE
    # Create the shared memory buffer
    shared_memory_block = sm.SharedMemory(name=SHARED_MEMORY_NAME,
        create=True, size=total_size)
    # Store the number of samples in the buffer
    putsize(shared_memory_block, len(data))
    # Store the data in the buffer
    for i in range(len(data)):
        put(shared_memory_block, i, *data.loc[i].values)
    # Wait
    print('ready - press ctrl-c to stop')
    try:
        input()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except:
        raise
    # When all processes are done, unlink the memory
    print('exiting ...')
    shared_memory_block.unlink()
    print('done!')
    # A testing block to demonstrate that data gets in and out
    #   All three lines should be exactly the same
    if True:
        smb2 = sm.SharedMemory(name=SHARED_MEMORY_NAME)
        print(list(data.loc[8].values))
        print(get(shared_memory_block, 8))
        print(get(smb2, 8))

# This function acts as the consumer of the data
#   Many of these consumers can exist at the same time
#   Consumers can also be started and stopped many times for a single provider
def consumer():
    print('consumer started')
    # Link to the shared memory block created by the producer
    #   If this line fails, check that the producer is in the 'ready' state
    shared_memory_block = sm.SharedMemory(name=SHARED_MEMORY_NAME)
    # Find out how many samples are available in the buffer
    total_samples = getsize(shared_memory_block)
    # Iterate through them, doing whatever it is that you need to do
    for i in range(total_samples):
        # Simply call 'get' on each index to retrieve the data
        mydata = get(shared_memory_block, i)
        print(mydata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'provider':
        provider()
    if sys.argv[1] == 'consumer':
        consumer()
    if sys.argv[1] == 'makedata':
        makedata()
```